# MYSQL How to get rid of duplicates

Tags: mysql, join, duplicates, subquery

I need the sum of two customers each so I wrote the following query:

```
SELECT m.m_name, m2.m_name AS m_name2, SUM(m.price + m2.price) as total_amount, rn.name 
FROM
(      
SELECT m.name AS m_name, m.id AS m_id ,IFNULL(SUM(d.num * p.price), 0) AS price
FROM m_member as m
LEFT JOIN t_sales AS t ON m.id = t.m_id
INNER JOIN m_product as p
LEFT JOIN t_sales_detail as d ON t.id = d.id AND p.id = d.p_id
GROUP BY m.id
)AS m 
LEFT JOIN 
(      
SELECT m.name AS m_name, m.id AS m2_id ,IFNULL(SUM(d.num * p.price), 0) AS price
FROM m_member as m
LEFT JOIN t_sales AS t ON m.id = t.m_id
INNER JOIN m_product as p
LEFT JOIN t_sales_detail as d ON t.id = d.id AND p.id = d.p_id
GROUP BY m.id
) AS m2 ON m.m_id != m2.m2_id
JOIN m_lank AS rn ON (SELECT SUM(m.price + m2.price)) BETWEEN rn.low_limit AND rn.up_limit
GROUP BY m.m_id, m2.m2_id
order by total_amount;
```

The results looks like this:

```
# m_name    m_name2    total_amount    name
Nagayama    Kawata         380        Bronze
Kawata      Nagayama       380        Bronze
Nagaoku     Kawata         500        Bronze
Kawata      Nagaoku        500        Bronze
Nagayama    Nagaoku        880        Bronze
Nagaoku     Nagayama       880        Bronze
Kawashima   Kawata         2620       Bronze
Kawata      Kawashima      2620       Bronze
...
```

The problem is, I don't need to sum the same customer two times.
How can I get rid of the duplicate results? Anyone has a solution?

EDIT:
I want something like this:

```
# m_name    m_name2    total_amount    name
Nagayama    Kawata         380        Bronze
Nagaoku     Kawata         500        Bronze
Nagayama    Nagaoku        880        Bronze
Kawashima   Kawata         2620       Bronze
...
```

Sorry for my poor English. It might be difficult to understand what I need.

Basically I have in total five customers.
Customer A has bought a total of 400$
Customer B has bought a total of 1030$.
Customer C .... 1540$.
Customer D .... 0$.
Customer F .... 320$.

Now I want to sum every customer with each other:

```
A + B
A + C
A + D
A + F
B + C
B + D
B + F
C + D
C + F
D + F
```

Comment: *I don't need to sum the same customer two times.* Do you mean this fragment: *`SUM(m.price + m2.price)`* ? If so use `CASE WHEN m.price = 0 THEN m2.price ELSE m.price END` instead.

Comment: This is a really convoluted way to do something. What results do you want? Edit question with some sample data and expected results.

Comment: @danblack I am sorry, I should have posted the expected results. I edited the question.

Comment: Which mysql version? There might be an easier way. So this is a CROSS JOIN where the self mapping is eliminated and also the B,A output mapping where a A,B exists?

Comment: @danblack I am using version 10.4.17. I basically joining the same subquery two times. I understand that therefore that each customer gets added up by each other. I just cant figure out how to avoid adding up the same two customers two times.

Comment: Use a [cte](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/non-recursive-common-table-expressions-overview/) (not recursive) to get the `id` and `sales total`. Use the CTE usage to `cte_tbl t1 JOIN cte_tbl t2 on t1.id < t2.id`. Then `JOIN m_member m1 ON m1.id = t1.id JOIN m_member m2 ON t2.id=m2.id` to fill out the names. Still stuck - provide a [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.4) link with *sample data* loaded into tables.

Comment: @danblack I provided the necessary tables including data: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.4&fiddle=f2fe55ff500204d2fe22a73074af9786

Honestly I havent heard from cte yet. I will check your link out! Thank you!

Comment: Thanks for updated question. Its very clear now. Hope you like the CTE answer. Don't apologize for your english, a) its easily understandable, b) not being a native speaker isn't something to apologize for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, it can be achieved with the minimal change to your query. Just replace `!=` with `<` or `>`. Thus you will get each pair only once.

```
SELECT m.m_name, m2.m_name AS m_name2, SUM(m.price + m2.price) as total_amount, rn.name 
FROM
(      
SELECT m.name AS m_name, m.id AS m_id ,IFNULL(SUM(d.num * p.price), 0) AS price
FROM m_member as m
LEFT JOIN t_sales AS t ON m.id = t.m_id
INNER JOIN m_product as p
LEFT JOIN t_sales_detail as d ON t.id = d.id AND p.id = d.p_id
GROUP BY m.id
)AS m 
LEFT JOIN 
(      
SELECT m.name AS m_name, m.id AS m2_id ,IFNULL(SUM(d.num * p.price), 0) AS price
FROM m_member as m
LEFT JOIN t_sales AS t ON m.id = t.m_id
INNER JOIN m_product as p
LEFT JOIN t_sales_detail as d ON t.id = d.id AND p.id = d.p_id
GROUP BY m.id
) AS m2 ON m.m_id > m2.m2_id
JOIN m_lank AS rn ON (SELECT SUM(m.price + m2.price)) BETWEEN rn.low_limit AND rn.up_limit
GROUP BY m.m_id, m2.m2_id
order by total_amount;
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I never thought about replacing "!=" with ">". It seemed logical for me to use "!=", so the same ID won't get summed up. But on the contrary, each pair adds up twice.
Anyway, thank you. I think my understanding of querying improved thanks to your answer!

Answer (score 1):

Using a CTE we get to reuse the table `user_totals` without a duplication:

```
WITH user_totals AS
  (SELECT s.m_id AS id,
          sum(sd.num*p.price) AS sales_amount
   FROM t_sales_detail sd
   JOIN m_product p ON sd.p_id=p.id
   JOIN t_sales s ON s.id=sd.id
   GROUP BY s.m_id)
SELECT m1.name,
       m2.name,
       t1.sales_amount+t2.sales_amount
FROM user_totals t1
JOIN user_totals t2 ON t1.id < t2.id
JOIN m_member m1 ON t1.id = m1.id
JOIN m_member m2 ON t2.id = m2.id
```

Like the other answer greater than/less than is a good JOIN criteria for getting only one match.

`!=` makes a bad join criteria as you're after a non-match on all rows, it rarely does what you expect.
An illustration of this is [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.4&fiddle=1838c41bf6c9eb829fb391e7dd867023)

Note: row limits and `IFNULL` criteria removed for readabilit

Comment: Thank you, I really appreciate your answer! I find this approach extremely interesting and it gave me another view to solve this problem. I will keep CTE in my mind.